# TreeWalker checks not working with Kotlin/Gradle?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, checkstyle

I want to use [CheckStyle (7.1)](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/checks.html) (older versions have the same problem) for a Kotlin program running with Gradle (2.14.1).

The normal modules/checks (ex `NewlineAtEndOfFile`, `FileTabCharacter`, ...) work like a charm, but none of the submodules of `TreeWalker` (ex `AvoidStarImport`) do.

The `gradle test` finishes `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` (and I'm 200% sure there should be style errors), and there are xx files but 0 errors in the `build/reports/checkstyle/main.html` file.

Does TreeWalker not work with Kotlin? I can't find any information about this :/

The configuration in the `build.gradle` file:

```
...

apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

...

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "7.1"
    configFile = new File(rootDir, "checkstyle.xml")
    checkstyleMain.source = "src/main/kotlin"
    checkstyleMain.ignoreFailures = false
    checkstyleMain.showViolations = true
}

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the source code](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/TreeWalker.java#L99) it is clear that `TreeWalker` activates only on files with `.java` extension:

```
    public TreeWalker() {
        setFileExtensions("java");
    }
```

Moreover, it uses [Java lexer](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/TreeWalker.java#L53) underneath, so it won't work for any other language.

As you've already noticed, all other checks are fine to use with any file/language.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I found in the documentation that I could force to check the *.kt files anyway but as you already mentionned the Java lexer did not like that at all.Some checks did work tho, but they drowned in hundreds of Java syntax notices ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any information that it *does* work with Kotlin, so it would be reasonable to assume that it doesn't, especially taking into account that it's a tool that automates the process of checking *Java* code.

Answer (score 0):

Checkstyle does not support Kotlin.

As an alternative, the IntelliJ IDEA Kotlin 1.1.50+ plugin supports checking the Kotlin code style against the settings configured for the project [(announced here)](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/09/kotlin-1-1-50-is-out/).

Currently this is only an IDE feature, but there's a work-in-progress Gradle plugin with the same functionality (not available yet).

[image]